# Check if all packages of a long list are available

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu

For a Kubuntu system I got a long list of dependencies I need to install for a manual software installation process. Before installing all of these packages I would like to check if they are actually available so I do not end with part of them installed.

Is there a way to "simulate" installation of a list of packages using apt-get? Or is there a way to check if packages exist before actually calling apt-get for installation?

Comment: You won't end up with a part of them installed if you tell apt-get to install all of them in one operation. In a single operation, if any package can't be found, apt-get simply doesn't install any.

Comment: @muru How can I do that? Is it enough to call apt-get a single time with all packages in a list? Or do I need some explicit option?

Comment: Yes, that should be enough. (E.g., `apt install foo vim zsh` will error out with `E: Unable to locate package foo`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [man apt-get](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> **-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act**
>
> No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system.

For example:

```sh
apt-get install -s package1 package2
```

Comment: Note the lack of `sudo` before --simulate. Since the system is not being changed, sudo is not necessary.